# '[UILabel]' does not have a member named 'text'

Tags: swift, interface-builder

After I upgrade to Xcode 6.3, it is failed to assign the String into the UILabel.  I got the Swift compiler error message "'[UILabel]' does not have a member named 'text'" on UILabel textLabel.  Any idea to fix it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameTxt: [UITextField]!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: [UILabel]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func changeLabel(sender: UIButton) {
        self.textLabel?.text = "Success"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are hooking up labels (or anything else) from the storyboard to our source code, we will get a pop-up menu that looks something like this:

[image]

When you click "Connect" here (all I did after getting the pop-up is type "textLabel", everything else is default), it will produce the following line of code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
```

However, "Outlet" is not the only option for connecting our objects from interface builder to source code.

If we change the "Connection" drop down to select "Outlet Collection", like so:

[image]

Then the line of code generated will match exactly the line of code in your question:

```
@IBOutlet var textLabel: [UILabel]!
```

We've created an array of labels.  This is useful in some cases, but perhaps not what we actually want here.

In order to fix this, we must first be sure to **unhook** our original connection (otherwise, we'll have runtime exceptions).

So, if you go back to Interface Builder and right click on the label in question, you'll receive a menu that looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the label is linked to a "Referencing Outlet Collection", but not a "Referencing Outlet"?  This is what we need to fix.  So, click the X for that connection to unlink it.  Now we can go to the source code and delete the `@IBOutlet` that was generated.

Now, rehook your label up as a regular "Outlet" and not an "Outlet Collection", and your `changeLabel` method will work perfectly fine as-is.

When your label is correctly hooked up as an "Outlet" rather than an "Outlet Collection", your interface builder right click menu will look like this:

[image]

<sup>(Notice the difference between this one and the previous image.)</sup>